# Stored Procedure not returning Unicode characters even when the tables and the variables are set as nvarchar

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

I have been working on a ASP.NET website which include various functionalities like add some data, modifying data downloading the data to excel.

Here when we download the data a stored proc is running which generate some queries which then are used to insert some data in a temp table, from which the data is downloaded in excel. Previously this system was working without any unicode encoding and was working fine. Now we are enhancing the system's capability to be able to handle special characters. We have changed all the table datatypes to nvarchar and also appended N' to the queries that are shooting via the ASP.NET code on the server. But when the data type of the variables in the stored proc is changed to nvarchar it returns an error stating 'Invalid syntax near ')''. So i kept the data type of the variables to varchar where as the data types of the columns of the tables are nvarchar. The data gets downloaded but i get ? where there were special characters in the table.

Please help as i am new in this domain and have been stuck on this issue from a long time.

Comment: So the issue is the `'Invalid syntax near ')''` error, what is the code that produces that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working like this:

```
if object_id('sample', 'U') is not null
 drop table sample;
create table sample (
  text nvarchar(50) null
)

insert into sample(text) values (N'fööbäär@?<*');
insert into sample(text) values (N'~©‚å®ƒ©¨Ω†∑');

select * from sample;

drop table sample;
```

Output:

```
text
-----------
fööbäär@?<*
~©‚å®ƒ©¨Ω†∑
```

When you post some of your code, it might be easier to help.